# Would it be feasible to set up a system to download large files via a camera and QR codes?

Tags: mobile, download, camera, qr-code

This is just something I was thinking about today that I've never seen actually used. I was wondering if anything like this exists, or if it would even be feasible to do.

Since QR codes can handle strings, would it be possible to have a framework that uses a phone camera to read a specially formatted QR code (or something like a QR code that can hold enough data, or multiples of such codes to fit the entire thing), and then translate the data into a usable file, rather than just using a QR code to provide a download link?

If this were feasible, what languages would be best to create it?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes.](http://android.appstorm.net/reviews/utilities/transfer-files-through-qr-codes-with-scansfer/) Scanfer does something similar. You'd just need the file to be >3000 bytes in size... fitting within these restrictions:

Numeric only    Max. 7,089 characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Alphanumeric    Max. 4,296 characters (0–9, A–Z [upper-case only], space, $, %, *, +, -, ., /, :)

Binary/byte Max. 2,953 characters (8-bit bytes)

Kanji/Kana  Max. 1,817 characters

Answer (score 0):

A QR code can store about 3000 bytes. It doesn't matter what those bytes represent.